Can present continuous mean "should"?


We are not having this conversation at all (Rose said, in the movie Titanic.)


Usually this sentence suggests the speaker is denying the fact that they are having this conversation, which doesn't make sense. According to the context, I can understand what she means is We shouldn't have this conversation at all. Can the present continuous tense in English express this meaning? For example, if I want to say that we should not copy his homework，can I say instead:


We are not copying his homework.



IMO it means "as far as the rest of the world is concerned, this conversation never took place." Using 'should' makes it a value judgement, and perhaps the conversation very much should have taken place, but is private. As for 2, that does not mean the same thing either. You should not copy the homework, but you may still be doing so.

@WeatherVane that really isn't the implication in this quote. It's an assertion that she doesn't want to have that conversation.

@DanielRoseman "not want" still doesn't paraphrase as "shouldn't". For example if someone is being told a "home truth" not wanting to hear it, and shouldn't be hearing it, are quite different.

And going back to 2, "we should not copy homework" implies that they are doing so. It's not equivalent to a denial.

I'm not disagreeing on that, I'm saying that your interpretation of the phrase is incorrect.

If you want to say that we should not copy his homework (but we are currently doing that), say "We should not be copying his homework". If we're not already doing it, just say "We should not copy his homework". Note that unless it's actually intended literally (to deny that we are currently doing it) "We are not copying his homework" doesn't exactly mean we shouldn't - the speaker is declaring (with forceful authority) that we will not do so. It's a strong command, so to avoid giving offense, don't use that format if speaking to someone who is "senior" to you.

It's not really a "should" sense so much as using present tense for the future, something that happens a lot. "We are not having this conversation" can be read as "We will not have this conversation." There is a "modal" sense because the speaker is trying to enforce their will on someone else, but they're doing it simply by stating their desire so strongly that it becomes declarative, saying that there is no other possibility.

Yes. Or We are not going to have this conversation. That’s simply an example of the pattern “We are [not] Xing,” (for any verb X) being a form of future tense. Compare, Tomorrow I’m seeing my grandchildren.

@PaulTanenbaum: That sentence is also a good example of the fact that English has no future tense (if you replace "tomorrow" with "now," it magically transforms into the present, but "tomorrow" and "now" are the same class of word, so the future must not be fully grammaticalized and is at least partly a semantic property of the sentence).

Saying « We are not doing X », while currently doing it, is not equivalent to saying « We shouldn’t be doing X », because in “shouldn’t” there remains the possibility of wanting to continue doing it while knowing that X is reprehensible.
« We are not doing X » rather means « I don’t want to do X, I wish we never did X, but since it happened I want X to stop now ».

In English, words like "should" and "can" are called modal verbs.  They often add uncertainty to a sentence. If you for the sentence without modal verbs, but from context it is clear that you are not stating a simple fact, it has the effect of indicating strong certainty.  It expresses an opinion as fact.
The most common example is with the modal verb "will", as in "The train will leave at 5pm"  If you say "The train leaves at 5pm" you express strong certainty (in this case because it follows a timetable).
Similarly by stating "We are not having this conversation" she expresses her opinion  "I don't want to have this conversation" or "Let's not have this conversation." as fact.  This is a rhetorical effect to shut down discussion or debate. It means "I won't have this conversation, and I won't discuss that with you either."

I upvoted your Answer and I don't understand what difference there might be between 'The train will leave at 5pm' and 'The train leaves at 5pm'… less so if the latter expresses strong(er) certainty.
Can you elucidate?

We use the simple present to talk about future events that we are certain, as they are on a timetable - this is quite a common example and should be in most text books

Thanks James, and I don't understand how that helps.
In what way are 'The train will leave at 5pm' and 'The train leaves at 5pm' different?
'The train is due to leave at 5pm' or 'The train should leave at 5pm' or even 'The train generally leaves (on time) at 5pm' are all clearly different and however childish my query seems, can you explain how or why 'The train will leave at 5pm' and 'The train leaves at 5pm' are not wholly interchangeable?

Yes, mostly interchangeable.  Please consult a textbook, I included this example as a common textbook example of omitting the modal verb.

Thanks James, and please cite some textbooks, or at least list a few of your favourites.
Otherwise, why would anyone accept your unsupported assertion?

As others have answered, Rose uses this statement to (attempt to) end the conversation, but note that “We are not having this conversation” is not as absurd as it may seem to you at first.
“This conversation” doesn’t necessarily refer to the conversation that Rose and Jack are having as a whole, which they obviously are having, but specifically to the topic that Jack has brought up, “Do you love Cal?”, a conversation which she is refusing to have with a stranger.
It’s not absurd for her to say “we are not having this conversation at all”, if it refers only to that topic, because Jack is pushing the issue, asking multiple times, while she refuses to engage that topic at all.
